# Simple Command Line Interpreter

Tags: c, terminal

I need to implement a simple command line interpreter, able to interpret a set of internally-implemented commands. I tried with this code but it doesn't work at all.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

#define MAXIMO 2048
#define BLANCO " "
#define FIN "FIN"
#define MSG_ERROR "ERROR!"
#define PROMPT "\n#@> "

int hayAmpersand(char cadena[]);

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    char comando[MAXIMO] = "";
    char *palabras[MAXIMO];
    int e, i, ampersand;
    pid_t hijo, hijoMuerto;

    while(1) {
        // Vacio las cadenas al inicio de cada bucle
        comando[0] = '\0';
        ampersand = 0;

        printf(PROMPT);
        scanf("\n%[^\n]", comando); // Leemos la cadena entera

        if (strcmp(comando, FIN) == 0)
            return (0); // Si son iguales sale del programa

        if (hayAmpersand(comando) == 1)
            ampersand = 1;

        //== Cadenas
        //==========================================================
        // Sacamos la primera palabra de la cadena
        palabras[0] = strtok(comando, BLANCO);

        // Sacamos la otras palabras de la cadena
        i = 1;
        while ((palabras[i] = strtok(NULL, BLANCO)) != NULL)
            i++;
        //== Fin Cadenas
        //======================================================

        hijo = fork();

        switch (hijo) {
          case -1:
            perror(MSG_ERROR);
            exit(-1);
          case 0:
            execvp(palabras[0], &palabras[0]);
            perror(MSG_ERROR);
            exit(e);
          default:
            if (ampersand != 1) {
                hijoMuerto = 0;
                while ((hijo != hijoMuerto) && (hijoMuerto != -1))
                    hijoMuerto = wait(&e);
            }
        }
    }
    return (0);
}

int hayAmpersand(char cadena[]) {
    int j = 0;

    for (j = 0; j <= strlen(cadena); j++) {
        if (cadena[j] == '&') {
            cadena[j] = cadena[j + 1];
            return(1);
        }
    }
    return (0);
}
```

Here is the exercise:
http://ciprianpungila.com/uvt/so2018/projects/35.txt

More or less it works but the exercise need to implement the keyboard arrows and I don't know how could I do this in my code, if someone can help me I will be very grateful

Comment: Are you allowed to use `readline`?

Comment: A simple google search of `c programming reading arrow keys` gives enough answers.

Comment: It would be helpful to your question if you could more specific, e.g. how do I capture the arrow keys, or, if you've already captured them, how do I move the cursor? Right now, your question is basically asking someone to do the assignment for you.

Comment: @jesusbedoya: you can accept one of the answers by clicking on the grey checkmark below its score.

Answer (score 1):

Command line editing is not part of the requirements. Neither are you explicitly barred from using `readline()` which may be available on your system and performs just that.

Note that your current implementation needs a lot more work to meet the actual requirements, so I suggest you focus on those instead of wasting time trying to re-implement a command line editor. Doing it properly is non trivial.

Note also that your use of `scanf()` is inappropriate for reading an input line: `scanf("\n%[^\n]", comando);` will indeed ignore any whitespace and read a command up to the next newline (excluded), but it will potentially write to memory beyond the end of the `commando` array, which causes undefined behavior. You should instead use `fgets()`, `readline()` or a custom written function to read the user's input. You would also detect end of file which may be useful :)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `scanf`, you can use `readline`:

```
char *command = readline(PROMPT);
```

However, I'm not sure you're allowed to use `readline` for your exercise...

Comment: You are one point away from reaching the next privilege. That must be tantalising :)

Comment: So what you are proposing is another way of not solving the problem? How does this answer the question?